# I am trying to eager load parameter in eloquent laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to eager load data from a many-to-many relationship in eloquent laravel 5.8. The below code was working in laravel 5.5 but now it is not working in my new version i.e. 5.8

```php
$data = Recruitment::find($id);

$candidates = $data->candidates()
    ->with([
        'status'=> function ($query) use ($id)
        {
            return  $query->where('recruitment_id', $id);
        },
        'interviews'=> function ($query) use ($id)
        {
            return  $query->where('recruitment_id', $id);
        },
        'contracts'=> function ($query) use ($id)
        {
            return  $query->where('recruitment_id', $id);
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ])->get();
```

My relation is as follows:

In **Recruitment.php**

```php
public function candidates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Candidate::class)->withPivot('status');
}
```

In **Candidate.php**

```php
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Recruitment::class, 'candidate_recruitment')
        ->select(['candidate_id','status']);
}
```

Result in **dump**:

```
#relations: array:1 [
    "status" => MediableCollection {
    #items: []
}
```

is giving me empty results. 
Am I missing something needed in the new version.
Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my English

**The following also is not working using whereHas:**

```
$candidates = Recruitment::
        with('candidates.status')
        ->whereHas('candidates.status', function ($query) use ($id){
            $query->where('recruitment_id', $id);

         })
         ->find($id);
```

**UPDATED with table structures:**

candidate_recruitment table

```
id | candidate_id  | recruitment_id  | status         
---------------------------------------------
 19 | 33           | 13              | 0
 20 | 30           | 13              | 0
 21 | 31           | 13              | 0
```

candidates table

```
id  | employee_no | name 
--------------------------
30  | 001         | john
31  | 002         | mike
32  | 003         | paul
```

Recruitments table

```
id | department_id| employee_status_id  | qualification_id
----------------------------------------------------------
 13| 1            | 1                   | 6
```

**UPDATES**

**This is output from enableQueryLog for laravel 5.5**

```
array:11 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select *, CONCAT(first_name, " ", surname) AS name, `candidates`.*, `candidate_recruitment`.`recruitment_id` as `pivot_recruitment_id`, `candidate_recruitment`. ▶"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 13
    ]
    "time" => 1.64
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `media`.*, `mediables`.`mediable_id` as `pivot_mediable_id`, `mediables`.`media_id` as `pivot_media_id`, `mediables`.`tag` as `pivot_tag`, `mediables`.`o ▶"
    "bindings" => array:5 [▼
      0 => 30
      1 => 31
      2 => 32
      3 => 33
      4 => "App\Candidate"
    ]
    "time" => 1.72
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `job_titles`.`id`, `job_titles`.`description` from `job_titles` where `job_titles`.`id` in (?) and `job_titles`.`deleted_at` is null"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => null
    ]
    "time" => 0.47
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `candidate_previous_employments` where `candidate_previous_employments`.`candidate_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?) and `candidate_previous_employments`.`delet ▶"
    "bindings" => array:4 [▼
      0 => 30
      1 => 31
      2 => 32
      3 => 33
    ]
    "time" => 0.52
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▶]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `candidate_id`, `status`, `candidate_recruitment`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `candidate_recruitment`.`recruitment_id` as `pivot_recruitment_ ▶"
    "bindings" => array:5 [▼
      0 => 30
      1 => 31
      2 => 32
      3 => 33
      4 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 0.6
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `interviews`.*, `candidate_interview_recruitment`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `candidate_interview_recruitment`.`interview_id` as `pivot_inte ▶"
    "bindings" => array:5 [▼
      0 => 30
      1 => 31
      2 => 32
      3 => 33
      4 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 1.0
  ]
  7 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `media`.*, `mediables`.`mediable_id` as `pivot_mediable_id`, `mediables`.`media_id` as `pivot_media_id`, `mediables`.`tag` as `pivot_tag`, `mediables`.`o ▶"
    "bindings" => array:2 [▼
      0 => 5
      1 => "App\Interview"
    ]
    "time" => 0.64
  ]
  8 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `candidate_id`, `comment`, `status`, `recruitment_status`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `recruitment_status`.`recruitment_id` as `pivot_recruit ▶"
    "bindings" => array:5 [▼
      0 => 30
      1 => 31
      2 => 32
      3 => 33
      4 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 0.92
  ]
  9 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `candidate_id`, `contract_id`, `start_date`, `signed_on`, `comments`, `contract_recruitment`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `contract_recruitmen ▶"
    "bindings" => array:5 [▼
      0 => 30
      1 => 31
      2 => 32
      3 => 33
      4 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 0.55
  ]
  10 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `candidate_id`, `offer_id`, `starting_on`, `signed_on`, `comments`, `offer_recruitment`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `offer_recruitment`.`offe ▶"
    "bindings" => array:5 [▼
      0 => 30
      1 => 31
      2 => 32
      3 => 33
      4 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 0.56
  ]
]
```

**This is output from enableQueryLog for laravel 5.8**

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select *, CONCAT(first_name, " ", surname) AS name, `candidate_recruitment`.`recruitment_id` as `pivot_recruitment_id`, `candidate_recruitment`.`candidate_id` a ▶"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 13
    ]
    "time" => 1.3
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `media`.*, `mediables`.`mediable_id` as `pivot_mediable_id`, `mediables`.`media_id` as `pivot_media_id`, `mediables`.`mediable_type` as `pivot_mediable_t ▶"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "App\Candidate"
    ]
    "time" => 0.76
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `job_titles`.`id`, `job_titles`.`description` from `job_titles` where 0 = 1 and `job_titles`.`deleted_at` is null"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.49
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `candidate_previous_employments` where `candidate_previous_employments`.`candidate_id` in (19, 20, 21, 22) and `candidate_previous_employments`.`d ▶"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.56
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `candidate_qualifications` where `candidate_qualifications`.`candidate_id` in (19, 20, 21, 22) and `candidate_qualifications`.`deleted_at` is null"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.53
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `candidate_id`, `status`, `candidate_recruitment`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `candidate_recruitment`.`recruitment_id` as `pivot_recruitment_ ▶"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 0.68
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `interviews`.*, `candidate_interview_recruitment`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `candidate_interview_recruitment`.`interview_id` as `pivot_inte ▶"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 0.95
  ]
  7 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `candidate_id`, `comment`, `status`, `recruitment_status`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `recruitment_status`.`recruitment_id` as `pivot_recruit ▶"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 0.64
  ]
  8 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `candidate_id`, `contract_id`, `start_date`, `signed_on`, `comments`, `contract_recruitment`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `contract_recruitmen ▶"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 0.6
  ]
  9 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `candidate_id`, `offer_id`, `starting_on`, `signed_on`, `comments`, `offer_recruitment`.`candidate_id` as `pivot_candidate_id`, `offer_recruitment`.`offe ▶"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "13"
    ]
    "time" => 0.89
  ]
]
```

**it is missing the candidates id...**

**I am getting the id of the pivot table instead of candidate_id...**
Any idea where this problem could be thanks...

Comment: Brain fog... I'm not grasping a clear picture of your database. What happens if you remove the `select` restriction in `Candidate.php`? Sometimes relations won't work if you don't select the correct columns.

Comment: @ShengSlogar Thanks for the reply, I have try this still getting empty array

Comment: what is really strange is that it is working for belongsTo but not for BelongsToMany

Comment: Eager loading gender is displaying data `public function gender() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Gender','gender_id','id');
    }`

Comment: How are you getting it to work with `belongsTo` without your pivot table? Another thing I would try is hard-coding all your relationship values, so `$this->belongsToMany(Recruitment::class, 'candidate_recruitment', 'candidate_id', 'recruitment_id');` and see if that gets you anywhere. **EDIT** `whereHas` also uses the same relationships as eager loading, so that makes sense. Are you getting your candidates to load at all, or just not their statuses?

Comment: @ShengSlogar I have tried this still not working. I have updated my question with dump of the **queryLog** for both version...Thanks